# Row wise mean difference in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, numpy

Given a pandas dataframe, whats the most efficient way to do row wise difference of rolling mean. i.e. if we have a dataframe as:

```
np.random.seed(43)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(6, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

which generated the dataframe as such:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  4  0  1  5
1  0  3  1  2
2  7  0  3  2
3  9  1  2  2
4  3  5  4  4
5  0  5  8  0
```

then the expected output is:

```
row_diff[0] = [row[0]['A'] - mean(row[1:]['A']), row[0]['B'] - mean(row[1:]['B']), row[0]['C'] - mean(row[1:]['C']), [row[0]['D'] - mean(row[1:]['D'])]]

row_diff[1] = [row[1]['A'] - mean(row[2:]['A']+row[0]['A']), row[1]['B'] - mean(row[2:]['B']+row[0]['B']), row[1]['C'] - mean(row[2:]['C']+row[0]['C']), [row[0]['D'] - mean(row[2:]['D']+row[0]['D'])]]
```

and so on.

Comment: What's the logic for `row[2:-1]` in the second row? is it excluding one from each end of the data? So your new data is about half length of the original?

Comment: Its to suggest cyclic calculation for the mean. Mean needs to be calculated on all other rows except for the one its currently being differenced from.

Comment: Yeah, then that's not what it means. `[2:-1]` is running from index `2` to the second-to-last index. Answer by @BrownBiggers is what you are looking for.

Comment: I see your point. Editing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm always confused about the best way to iterate in Pandas. Maybe something like matrix subtraction?

```py
result = df - ((df.sum(axis=0) - df)/(len(df) - 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be as simple as

```py
new_rows = pd.DataFrame([i - (sums - i) / (len(df) - 1) for _, i in df.iterrows()])
```